# Can you run a 32bit compiled webpart in 64bit SharePoint?

Tags: 2007, web-part

I have a webpart which needs to use a native 32bit DLL for data access (the dll is  Advantage.Data.Provider, for the Advantage Database Server DBMS.)  As such I'm pretty sure I need to compile it as 32bit.  However, my SharePoint server is 64bit.

If I compile the webpart project with platform target as x86, the webpart doesn't appear for me when trying to populate the web part gallery (_layouts/NewDwp.aspx).

(And if I compile the webpart with target 'Any CPU', the webpart appears in the gallery and I can add it, but when I try to add it to a page I get "Unable to load DLL 'ace32.dll'".  I guess this is because it's running 64bit and trying to access a 32bit DLL.)

Can I use 32bit webpart in 64bit SharePoint?  Or maybe there's another way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that SP2010 won't load a webpart compiled x86 only. Compiling with the target 'any CPU' means it will get Jitted to 64-bit when run inside the 64-bit worker process. That will prevent loading any 32-bit DLLs, as you say in the question.

You either need an 'ace64.dll', or load your db access code in another process somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Whats the version of Advantage Data Provider you are using?

I saw this similar thread, which says that the New Release of Data Provider would be 64-bit.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273887/sybase-advantage-database-server-and-64-bit-vfp-ole-providers

Did you get chance to download the new version?

Comment: We're on ADS unfortunately, so can't get the 64bit provider it seems..